# How can I get a specific metadata value of a Google Compute Engine instance?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcutil

I was wondering how to get the value of a specific metadata for a given instance in GCE.

For now I can view all the instance property with :

```
gcutil getinstance instance-test
```

But it returns all the metadata and I can not find a "filter" option in the gcutil documentation.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't know what the output from gcutil looks like, but the Unix Way (TM) would be to pipe the output into a separate "filter" program (grep, sed, awk, a perl script, etc.)

Comment: For now I use sed like that : 
`gcutil getinstance instance-test 2> /dev/null | grep ".*METADATA.*[a-zA-Z0-9-]*.*" | sed "s/ //g" | sed "s/|//g" | sed "s/METADATA//g"`

But this solution works only if our metadata value contains only letters, numbers and hyphen.

Comment: If you want few output examples : [Storing and Retrieving Metadata](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#updatinginstancemetadata)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have gcutil output into JSON format instead of tabular format by using the `--format` flag (see gcutil --help):

```
--format: <table|sparse|json|csv|names>: Format for command output. Options include:
  table: formatted table output
  sparse: simpler table output
  json: raw json output (formerly --print_json)
  csv: csv format with header
  names: list of resource names only, no header
  (default: 'table')
```

For example:

```
gcutil --format=json getinstance instance-test
```

Combine this with the [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for easy, powerful commands:

```
$ gcutil --format=json --service_version=v1 --project="<project>" \
      --zone="<zone>" getinstance "<instance>" | jq '.metadata.kind'
"compute#metadata"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was using an old version of the gcutil tool without format option.